# List GetEnumerator return type does not match interface

Tags: c#, .net, list, collections, interface

In visual studio 2015, when I go to List.cs and see class declaration, I see only one method named GetEnumerator:

```
public Enumerator GetEnumerator();
```

On the other hand, the interface IEnumerable<T> and IEnumerable specifies that it must define method whose format is:

```
IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator();
IEnumerator GetEnumerator();
```

This made me believe that interface method can be implemented even though the reuturn type does not excatly match. Although, that turned out to be wrong when I tried.

What is happening here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the source you will see two different GetEnumerator methods:

```
public Enumerator GetEnumerator() {
    return new Enumerator(this);
}

IEnumerator<T> IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator() {
    return new Enumerator(this);
}
```

The second one is only used if you are accessing the object through the IEnumerator interface.  They both do use the same underlying implementation however.

```
[Serializable]
public struct Enumerator : IEnumerator<T>, System.Collections.IEnumerator
{
  ...
}
```

You can still get to the strongly typed version as follows:

```
var exampleList = new List<string>();
var enumerator1 = ((IEnumerable<string>)exampleList).GetEnumerator()
var enumerator2 = (IEnumerable<string>) exampleList.GetEnumerator()
```

For `enumerator1` you are casting the list to use the GetEnumerator() method for the IEnumerable interface.  For `enumerator2` you are relying on the fact that the same implementation is used in in each and therefore you can just cast the enumerator.

Comment: Does that mean not that the class had no implementation, in metadata view, I could not see explicit implementation of GetEnumerator as it was private?

Comment: You can cast to see the strongly typed implementation. I'll edit my post above to make that clear.

Comment: Thanks, it was helpful

Answer (score 0):

The interface is implemented explicitly.  The method you're seeing is not the interface implementation, it's a separate method for the class.